# Best way to filter output by date range

Tags: bash, grep, awk, csv

I need to filter a row of a csv file by a date.

The file is structured as so:

```
test121smith@example.com                                           active      01/24/11 10:04   07/23/23 16:56
test121johnson@example.com                                              active      04/07/14 15:56   04/23/21 04:02
test121doe@example.com                                               active      07/27/12 16:24   11/13/12 01:14
test121fritts@example.com                                             active      11/02/10 14:00   09/05/14 11:34
test121violet@example.com                                              active      05/19/11 18:11   03/25/15 12:22
test121brad@example.com                                              active      06/26/14 12:45   03/05/19 20:27
```

I was able to sort by date using:

```
awk '{print $1 "," $3 "," $5}' | sort -t "," -n -k 2.7,5 -k 2.8,5 -k 2.1,5 -k 2.2,5 -k 2.4,5 -k 2.5,5
```

This gives me the rows sorted by date.

Example:

```
test121smith@example.com,01/24/11,07/23/23
test121johnson@example.com,04/07/14,04/23/21
test121doe@example.com,07/27/12,11/13/12
```

Is there a way to filter this output by date? Say print only rows after 12/11/22,  or only print rows before 12/11/22 for a given field or column?

What I tried:

```
grep -e '[3-9].$' -e '2[3-9]$' -e '12/[1-3]./22$' myfile.csv
```

As for output, this command filters the $3 third row. So the output for this sample example is:

```
test121smith@example.com,01/24/11,07/23/23
```

This worked, but only for one date in the 3rd column, and I didn't really grasp what it does, or how to change it depending on the date ranges the data is requested.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.0/installing-miller/), a nice CSV aware cli.

You could run in example

```
mlr --nidx --repifs filter 'strptime($3,"%m/%d/%y")>strptime("11/13/12","%m/%d/%y")' input.csv
```

to filter all the records of the third field (`$3`) greater than `11/13/12`, to have

```
test121johnson@example.com active 04/07/14 15:56 04/23/21 04:02
test121brad@example.com active 06/26/14 12:45 03/05/19 20:27
```

Some notes:

- `--nidx --repifs` to set the data format, index-numbered (toolkit style) with field sepator repeated (the space)
- [`filter`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.0/reference-verbs/index.html#filter), the verb to apply filters to fields
- `strptime`, the function to set the date format.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already sorted list, try below commands

```
$ cat a.txt

test121smith@example.com,01/24/11,07/23/23 

test121johnson@example.com,04/07/14,04/23/21

test121doe@example.com,07/27/12,11/13/12
```

Filter all lines before string matched including matched line

```
$ cat a.txt | sed '/04\/23\/21/q' # use escape sequence for date 04\/23\/21

test121smith@example.com,01/24/11,07/23/23

test121johnson@example.com,04/07/14,04/23/21
```

Filter all lines after string matched including matched line

```
$ cat a.txt | sed -n '/04\/23\/21/,$p' # use escape sequence for date 04\/23\/21 

test121johnson@example.com,04/07/14,04/23/21

test121doe@example.com,07/27/12,11/13/12
```

Comment: When I try either sed command I get "sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `2'"
I am using version 4.2.2 of sed.

Comment: Can you share what exactly you have ran along with output and attach it to question?

Comment: Output added. Hope it helps.

Comment: I mean share complete command and it's output which gives you "sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `2'".